# Can we calculate AES-CBC-PKCS7 ciphertext length based on the length of the plaintext?

Tags: aes, cbc, padding

I am currently using AES256 in CBC mode with PKCS7 Padding to encrypt some data. It seems like the output size is not always a power of two, which was what I expected.

Is it possible to calculate the size in bytes of the output, knowing only the input data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PKCS7 uses mandatory padding. Even if the length of your data is a multiple of your block size, it will pad.

```
output_size = input_size + (block_size - (input_size % block_size))
```

Answer (score 6):

AES is a block cipher with 128-bit block (regardless of its key size of 128, 192 or 256 bits); that is 16 octets. PKCS#7 padding adds from one octet to a full block. It thus transforms $n$ octets of plaintext into $16\lfloor n/16+1\rfloor$ octets of padded plaintext, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ $x$ rounded down to integer. Equivalently, the padded size is $n+16-(n\bmod 16)$ octets. In C(++), Java or Go, that's `(n|15)+1`.

Size of the ciphertext when enciphering in CBC mode is typically larger, because secure use of the CBC mode requires an IV, typically included in the ciphertext, often 8 or 16 octets. With `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc` the IV is 8 octets, but there is also an 8-octet header (`Salted__` in ASCII). So in the end the ciphertext is 16 octets more than the padded plaintext. Again, that depends on the program.

There's no reason that the output size be a power of two in CBC mode, and it usually is not.

Comment: `openssl enc` is probably not a good example; it stores _salt_ (8 octets regardless of cipher) plus the fixed string `Salted__`, and _derives_ the IV along with the key; see #3298. For CBC IV is one data block (varies depending on cipher); for GCM and CCM IV would probably be different (plus there would be no block padding) but that doesn't matter because `enc` format doesn't support any AEAD (or separate auth, for that matter)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got the power of two. With AES, your output will always be a multiple of the block size (16 bytes or 128 bits).

With PKCS7, if your input is already a multiple of 16 bytes, then an extra block is added for padding. If your input is not a multiple of 16 bytes, then round up to the nearest multiple of 16.

Some examples:

```
Input: 1 byte   output: 16 bytes
Input: 15 bytes output: 16 bytes
Input: 16 bytes output: 32 bytes
```

And a small nit pick: the size is technically determined before AES encryption. The padding is applied first to obtain 16 byte blocks, then AES is applied to everything.

Comment: That's without IV, thus unsafe for multiple encryptions! Most serious programs will add an IV, and the size will be different, and larger.

Comment: True, this only talks about the data size itself. How encryption context is stored is up to the user/program. It could be in the same file using a known format, or it could be stored separately from the data.